# Global variable not acting very globally

Tags: python, variables, module, global

So I have the following module named examplemod:

```
def maybeglobal():
    global test
    test = [1, 2, 3]
```

I then import the module and run the function:

```
import examplemod
examplemod.maybeglobal()
```

When I try to reference the new (supposedly) global variable test, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

I'm running 2.6.6 and have been currently banging my head into a wall for about two hours now. Do I just not understand how global is supposed to work? Because I'm pretty sure this is exactly what global is for.

Also, before people get at me for using global variables, the whole purpose of the function I'm working on is to have the custom class object that a module function creates accessible to the user for manipulation.

Comment: Try `examplemod.test`.

Answer (score 0):

It's global at the module level. So you need to do `examplemod.test` and you will get your expected answer.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. So is there a way to make 'test' able to be directly called without having to define the object in the local namespace?